# What is the cause of not being able to divide numbers in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, arm

i'm having a very strange situation. Every time I try to compile my arm project (LPC2378, codesourcery arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.5.1) I am left with the same error whilst linking

```
/media/data/Projects/arm/uart/main.c:39: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
/media/data/Projects/arm/uart/main.c:40: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
```

The offending code looks like this:

```
U0DLL = ((((PLLCFG & 0x7FFF) + 1) * F_OSC) / ((((PLLCFG & (0xFF << 16)) >> 16) + 1) * ((CCLKCFG & 0xFF) + 1) * 8 * BAUD * 1)) % 256;
U0DLM = ((((PLLCFG & 0x7FFF) + 1) * F_OSC) / ((((PLLCFG & (0xFF << 16)) >> 16) + 1) * ((CCLKCFG & 0xFF) + 1) * 8 * BAUD * 1)) / 256;
```

I've searched around and what this can be caused by, AFAICT, not using lgcc & lc options for LD. I've resolved that and still the error remains.

The full project can be [found at my github repo](https://github.com/regomodo/lpc2378-projects/tree/master/uart).

If anybody could help it would be greatly received. Cheers.

Comment: The order of linker flags sometimes matter, try: `$(LD) -o main.out  startup.o target.o fio.o irq.o main.o $(LDFLAGS)`

Comment: Banthar you star. I've been pulling my hair out for ages and the best of result I could find from Googling that function  are bug reports, the best being from RMS 6years ago.

Comment: Banthar: So is it best to put the linker flags last then?

Comment: @Regomo: You have to put the *libraries* after your own object files because of the way missing symbols are resolved. All the other flags can come in any order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ARM family of CPUs does not have a native integer division instruction. So, division needs to be implemented by a library function. GCC knows this, and creates a reference to (in your case) `__aeabi_uidiv` (for `unsigned int` division).

You will need to link with an appropriate runtime support library that contains this function.

Comment: From grepping the linked directory the appropriate library was being linked. It turns out it was the order of linking that caused the  error as banthar pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue and resolved it by passing the proper location of the `libgcc.a` in the `Makefile`. You may have to add:

```
"-L*path_to_libgcc.a* -lgcc"
```

to LDFLAGS

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a toolchain problem - perhaps your gcc is built for ARM EABI but your libraries (libgcc?) were built for traditional ABI?

Answer (score 0):

I normally avoid divides, when I have to use one, sometimes I hit this problem.  The (assembler) source for those division functions are in the gcc sources, not too hard to extract that code and just link it in when gcc doesnt cooperate.  Once you have a version with the macros removed, etc, a clean source, you can just carry that around in your back pocket.  Googling I had found at one time that the suggestion was to use the non linux eabi, but as you have found that doesnt always work, sometimes but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Check, whether your libgcc.a resides in the codesourcery directory where it should be. I had the same issue with TI starterware, which fixed the path to libgcc.a in one of the makefiles.

Comment: The link you have provided to your product website does not contain any information about the error in this question. It is not at all appropriate to include such unrelated links like this - especially when they are self-promotional. I am removing the link for you so your answer is not marked as spam.

Comment: I though that the message at the web page is clear. i wrote it to myself because I encountered exactly the same problem but using different sources: 1) you get __aeabi_uidiv error when not linking to libgcc.a 2) libgcc.a is a part of codesourcery 3) it is stored in versioned directory 4) if your makefile hooks to incorrect version, it simply does not work. I'm not going to repeat here what I've written already elsewhere, thus the link. If you find it inappropriate, then let it be. (in fact I would delete the post, but it does not get deleted, it is just flaggedd)