# How do I link the correct library so __aeabi_idiv and __aeabi_idivmod work?

Tags: c, makefile, arm, raspberry-pi

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576517/what-is-the-cause-of-not-being-able-to-divide-numbers-in-gcc) is the question I'm following up on. I have the same problem as regomodo did in that thread way back in 2011:

I'm trying to run a little program on my Raspberry Pi, and I'm using operators that aren't natively supported by ARM:

```
hello.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
hello.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_idivmod'
```

I understand that I need to link a library that knows about division and modding, but I can't quite get that to work (newbie to the Makefile life).

So I gave it a kind of pathetic stab and tried just adding the -lgcc:

```
LDFLAGS  = -L../lib -lgcc
```

that wasn't super fruitful:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lgcc
```

any advice would be so appreciated.

[edit1] here's the start of my makefile:

```
ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi

CPPFLAGS = -I../include
CFLAGS = $(ARCHFLAGS) -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding
LDFLAGS  = -L../lib -lgcc
LIBS = -lpi
```

Comment: Where is your `libgcc.a` archive located and what does your makefile look like?

Comment: yes! those were the words I was looking for. I'm trying to set up a libgcc.a archive— can I just download the .a file from somewhere? All [these](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libgcc.a.298384-0.html) links seemed broken.

Comment: update: found a copy of libgcc.a in the trash, moved it into my libs folder. now I'm changing my Makefile.

Comment: yes! libgcc.a was absolutely the issue: not in the path! thank you so much. This feels like a silly question now, but you absolutely were crucial in setting me on the right track. want to make an answer so I can give it a checkmark?

Comment: gcc knows where it was spawned from and where to find things (libgcc.a) when it calls ld, but ld does not, so for ld you have to explicitly provide the path either in the .a or a -L, or (groan) just use gcc to do your linking...

Comment: ^ that is so good to know! Thank you so much, I really felt like a fish out of water for not being able to do the most simple thing: link a library.

Comment: have you tried using rdimon.specs or nosys.specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `libgcc.a` archive is in the path you specify in your Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I know is quite late, but I was having the same problem, I'm using ArchLinux and it turns out that the libgcc.a file was not located at

```
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/
```

and/or its child folders which is the default installation directory for arm-none-eabi compiler in my system, instead, the libgcc.a library is located at

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/(version)
```

So whatever system you're using, you should look for that library in your default lib directory.