# symbol '__aeabi_uidiv' not found for arm-none-eabi

Tags: gcc, stm32

I know this question has been asked several times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576517/what-is-the-cause-of-not-being-able-to-divide-numbers-in-gcc) for example) but so far none of the replies I've found seems to apply to my situation.

On Debian stretch, gcc version 6.3.0, gcc-arm-none-eabi version 5.4.1, trying to build for a STM32L072.

Here is the Makefile I am using:

```
TARGET=main
TOOL_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1
BLDDIR = ./src/
BINDIR = ./build

VECT_TBL   = $(BLDDIR)startup.s
AS_SRC     = $(BLDDIR)core.s
C_SRC      = $(BLDDIR)main.c

OBJS  = $(VECT_TBL:.s=.o)
OBJS += $(AS_SRC:.s=.o)
OBJS += $(C_SRC:.c=.o)

TOOL=arm-none-eabi-
CC=$(TOOL)gcc
CXX=$(TOOL)g++
LD=$(TOOL)ld
AS=$(TOOL)as
OC=$(TOOL)objcopy
OD=$(TOOL)objdump
OS=$(TOOL)size

ARCH = -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mlittle-endian -march=armv6s-m -mthumb
COMMON_OPTS = -c -Wall
CC_OPTS  = -mlong-calls -ffunction-sections --specs=nosys.specs
DBG_OPTS = -O0 -g

CCFLAGS  = $(ARCH) $(COMMON_OPTS) $(CC_OPTS) $(DBG_OPTS) -DSTM32L072xx
ASFLAGS  = $(ARCH) $(COMMON_OPTS)
LDFLAGS  = -nostdlib
LDFLAGS += -L $(TOOL_PATH)/ -lgcc

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET).bin

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T $(BLDDIR)/link.ld $^ -o $@

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET).bin: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
    $(OC) -S -O binary $< $@
    $(OS) $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm $(OBJS)
    rm $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
```

I have double checked that libgcc.a exists at that path and contains the symbol with `nm`, and verified with `make -d`, but can't find a clue why the symbol is still not defined.

I have noticed that there are other folders containing the file libgcc.a that could match the architecture I am using:

- thumb
- armv6-m (not exactly the same name as used in `-march` but close enough to be worth a try)

but no luck so far.

Any idea about how to fix that, or to at least find some tracks?

Comment: Have you tried `armv6-m` instead of `armv6s-m`? The only difference between `armv6s-m` and `armv6-m` is the SVC instruction, which is mandatory by now. So there shouldn't be any difference anymore regarding generated code.

Comment: you mean, in the Makefile on the ARCH variable? Just tried it after reading you, but still no luck.

Comment: Try to move a `$^` argument before `$(LDFLAGS)` when linking the .elf. The order of objects and libraries matters, the library should come after the objs, so the imported symbols will be resolved.

Comment: @Vlad: please make this an answer, since it fixed my issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move a $^ argument before $(LDFLAGS) when linking the .elf.
The order of objects and libraries matters, the library should come after the objs.

The reason is how the linker works. The behavior will depend on the actual linker, and for "typical UNIX linker" files will be processed sequentially. The reference to external symbol will be searched in the code (obj/lib) that follows the file with that reference. If library was specified before the object files that needs it, "unused" function from the library will not be found later.